# Sorting list-within-list in Python

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have a list within a list that is in this format:

```
[['39.9845450804', '-75.2089337931', 'Paved', ' ', 5.974380011873201],
['39.977111208', '-75.1326105278', 'Asphalt', '8', 3.4881723880136537],
['39.9767607107', '-75.1328155113', 'Asphalt', '20', 1.5123970222417986],
['40.089750884', '-74.9852538861', 'Paved', ' ', 4.296923142303416]]
```

Where the indices are `latitude`, `longitude`, `type of pavement`, `no. of empty spots`, and `location in KM from my current location`

I want to sort this unsorted list from the greatest to lowest by my 4-th index, which is the `location in KM from my current location`. You can assume that the list-within-list will will contains the same total number of data points of five.

I know to use `sort()` for single-dimensional lists, but I am not quite sure how to sort lists within lists.

Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python - sort list of list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5758254/python-sort-list-of-list)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `my_data` is your list then to sort by the 5th element in `my_data` you do:

```
sorted(my_data, key=lambda data: data[4])
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `key` parameter:

```
a = [['39.9845450804', '-75.2089337931', 'Paved', ' ', 5.974380011873201],
['39.977111208', '-75.1326105278', 'Asphalt', '8', 3.4881723880136537],
['39.9767607107', '-75.1328155113', 'Asphalt', '20', 1.5123970222417986],
['40.089750884', '-74.9852538861', 'Paved', ' ', 4.296923142303416]]

sorted(a, key=lambda entry: entry[4])
```

Gives:

```
[['39.9767607107', '-75.1328155113', 'Asphalt', '20', 1.5123970222417986], ['39.977111208', '-75.1326105278', 'Asphalt', '8', 3.4881723880136537], ['40.089750884', '-74.9852538861', 'Paved', ' ', 4.296923142303416], ['39.9845450804', '-75.2089337931', 'Paved', ' ', 5.974380011873201]]
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a [key](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#index-30) argument in sort:

```
from operator import itemgetter
data.sort(key=itemgetter(4))
```

Comment: And `operator.itemgetter()` is also documented [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter).