# Sort list in ascending and descending order

Tags: python

I have list of list. i want sort the list according to the date

```
list=[["rohit", "2004-10-01"],["rishu", "2004-10-05"],["gaurav", "2004-10-09"],["sony", "2004-10-03"],["zee", "2004-1-01"]]
```

i want to sort the list according to date

Comment: First, provide valid Python. Second, search first. eg. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29870209/sorting-list-within-list-in-python

Answer (score 0):

The `list.sort` function can take the argument `key` which specifies how to calculate the key to sort the array. You can pass in a lambda expression such that the second element of the inner list is selected to sort the `list`.

Example -

```
>>> lst = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,1]]
>>> lst.sort(key = lambda x: x[1])
>>> lst
[[5, 1], [1, 2], [3, 4]]
```

For sorting in descending order, use `reverse` parameter of the sort function and set it to `True` .

Example -

```
>>> lst = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,1]]
>>> lst.sort(key = lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
>>> lst
[[3, 4], [1, 2], [5, 1]]
```

---

You can also use `operator.itemgetter(1)` to get the second element of the inner list to sort, the `1` as the paramter indicates which element to select.

Example -

```
>>> import operator
>>> lst = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,1]]
>>> lst.sort(key = operator.itemgetter(1))
>>> lst
[[5, 1], [1, 2], [3, 4]]
>>> lst.sort(key = operator.itemgetter(1) ,reverse=True) # descending order.
>>> lst
[[3, 4], [1, 2], [5, 1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list=[["rohit", "2004-10-01"],["rishu", "2004-10-05"],["gaurav", "2004-10-09"],["sony", "2004-10-03"],["zee", "2004-1-01"]]
print list
from datetime import datetime
dt = datetime.strptime("2004-10-01", "%Y-%m-%d")
list.sort(key=lambda x:datetime.strptime(x[1], "%Y-%m-%d"))
print list
```

I assumed year month date format you can change the format by replacing "%Y-%m-%d" to "%Y-%d-%m" if you are following year date month format

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import datetime
>>> a_list = [['rohit', '2004-10-01'],['rishu', '2004-10-05'],['gaurav', '2004-10-09'],['sony', '2004-10-03'],['zee', '2004-1-01']]
>>> sorted( a_list, key = lambda (x): datetime.datetime.strptime(x[1], '%Y-%m-%d').date() )                    [['zee', '2004-1-01'], ['rohit', '2004-10-01'], ['sony', '2004-10-03'], ['rishu', '2004-10-05'], ['gaurav', '2004-10-09']]
```

- `datetime.datetime.strptime(x[1], '%Y-%m-%d').date() )` returns a [`datetime.date`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#available-types) object. You can do normal comparisons on date objects like

  ```
  >>> d1 = datetime.datetime.strptime('2004-10-01', '%Y-%m-%d').date()
  >>> d2 = datetime.datetime.strptime('2004-10-05', '%Y-%m-%d').date()                                           
  >>> d1 < d2
  True
  ```

Comment: why it is important to fetch date() part rather than using the complete date object for comparison ?

Comment: @k4vin No specific reasons, you can do that as well.